# Pandas - Extract Text from Rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Let's say I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(['Apple, 10/01/2016, 31/10/18, david/kate', 'orange', 'pear', 'Apple', '10/01/2016', '02/20/2017'], columns=['A'])

>>> df2

                                         A       file_name
0  Apple, 10/01/2016, 31/10/18, david/kate          a.txt
1                                   orange          a.txt
2                                     pear          b.txt
3                                    Apple          a.txt
4                               10/01/2016          d.txt
5                               02/20/2017          e.txt
```

What I would like is to just extract the dates in this dataframe, so output would be like this:

```
                        A        file_name
0    10/01/2016, 31/10/18           a.txt
1    Nothing to return              a.txt
2    Nothing to return              b.txt
3    Nothing to return              a.txt
4    10/01/2016                     d.txt
5    02/20/2017                     e.txt
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this? I am not sure where to begin.

**Edit #1:**

I edited my original dataframe and output results to better reflect what I am looking for.

Comment: Please do not keep on editing the question and adding your requirement after receiving the answers here

Comment: I'm done editing, sorry, but I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `extractall` add `reindex(df2.index).fillna('Nothing to return')`

```
df2.A.str.extractall(r'(((?:\d+[/-])?\d+[/-]\d+))')[0].groupby(level=0).apply(','.join)
Out[459]: 
0    10/01/2016,31/10/18
4             10/01/2016
5             02/20/2017
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Update

```
df2.A.str.extractall(r'(((?:\d+[/-])?\d+[/-]\d+))')[0].groupby(level=0).apply(','.join).reindex(df2.index).fillna('Nothing to return')
Out[463]: 
0    10/01/2016,31/10/18
1      Nothing to return
2      Nothing to return
3      Nothing to return
4             10/01/2016
5             02/20/2017
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Comment: This works, but I made a small edit to my post, what if I wanted to keep the records that did not return anything?

Comment: Made one last and final change. I promise I'm done editing it this time :)

Comment: @LunchBox no worry :-)

Comment: Interesting, it works but I am curious as to why we did not have to escape the forward slash, "/" ?

Comment: Although, it could have something to do with the regex editor I was using, https://regex101.com/

Comment: Wen: your solution works, but it returns stuff like 000000-00-00. I wonder if there is a way to ignore values that are greater than 4 (I chose 4 because the date could be anywhere). I tried to modify your code by using d{1,4} but that was just doing a substring on the characters returned.

Comment: @LunchBox do this before implement my method `df2=df2.replace({'\d{5,}':'aaaaaa'},regex=True)
`

Comment: That's brilliant wen, but I encountered another problem. If I have a value like 0000-0000-0000-0000-0000, it's returning 0000-0000-0000, I need to ignore those completely as those aren't dates.

Comment: LOL, well, it's probably some sort of ID value or something. I took a SQL query and joined it into being 1 line. It's doing filters on various criteria, but I'm just trying to extract any dates.

Comment: I did modify what you gave me earlier. It was grabbing values that were things like "10-26" so I changed it to this: (r'(((?:\d+[/-])\d+[/-]\d+))'), basically, I removed the question marks.

Comment: I think what I might try to do is add (d+[/-]?)+ at the end. This will give me the entire value instead of just the first 3 sections, i.e. if I have a value like 0000-0000-0000-0000-0000, it returns 0000-0000-0000 right now. I will then try to count the number of "-" and "/" marks in the value. If this is greater than 2, I will filter the entire row out.

Comment: @LunchBox it all depends on you actual data , you may need to investigate on it .

Comment: it's just a sql query, so it contains  "select columns from table where various criteria" that's literally the value in each cell in the column I'm trying to extract from. I imported a bunch of ".sql" files as text

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't exactly match your desired output but this structure is probably better and can be easily converted into what you want.

Basically this is a job for regex. This code should find anything of the form number/number/number:

```
s = df2["A"]
result = s.str.extractall(r"(\d+/\d+/\d+)")[0]
print(result)

>>>    match
    0  0        10/01/2016
       1          31/10/18
    4  0        10/01/2016
    5  0        02/20/2017
```

Comment: Edited original post, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime
import re
def my_func(row):
    temp=''
    for d in row.split(","):
        match=re.match('(\d*/\d*/\d*)',d.strip())
        if match:
            temp =temp + match.group(0)+','
    if(temp):
        return temp[:-1]
    return "Nothing to return"
df2.A=df2.A.apply(lambda x : my_func(x))
```

Output:

```
                        A        file_name
0    10/01/2016, 31/10/18           a.txt
1    Nothing to return              a.txt
2    Nothing to return              b.txt
3    Nothing to return              a.txt
4    10/01/2016                     d.txt
5    02/20/2017                     e.txt
```

Comment: Edited post, I promise I'm done editing it this time :)